# compiling [Head|Tail] to SQL

Tags: sql, compiler-construction, prolog

Prolog constructs are list oriented, since lists allow to merge the `tuple-at-once` Prolog model to the `all-solutions` relational model (SQL, let's say).

I was thinking about to compile list processing Prolog code to SQL.

I think Draxler's compiler [pl2sql](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/prolog/code/io/pl2sql/0.html) does not address the problem (appropriately, the term `list` is never used...).

I was thinking about a column to pair translation,

```
append(A,B,C) ~~>
    table(append, A_key,A_val, B_key,B_val, C_key,C_val)
```

where _key would be row IDs, and express relations with different self joins, selected depending on instancing status of head' Variables.

The alternative design could be

```
append(A,B,C) ~~>
    table(append_A, key, val), table(append_B, key, val), table(append_C, key, val)
```

with joins, instead of self joins as above.

Does anyone know about precedent work ?

What about about feasibility ? In particular, could stored procedure be avoided ?

*edit* I've found [FunSQL](http://www.edbt.org/Proceedings/2012-Berlin/papers/workshops/danac2012/a1-binnig.pdf) document, should be relevant... going to read.

Comment: The lack of a part-of construct in SQL was one of the "knocks" on it by proponents of pre-relational data modelling (network, hierarchical, CODASYL).  Typical "solutions" by SQL proponents feature awkward self-joins on tables, not really convincing to their critics, but good enough for real world applications.

Answer (score 1):

The first normal form of the relational database model 
says that table columns should only store scalar values.

But nobody prevents you from violating this constraints. 
You can use some serialization of non scalar values to 
store non scalar values in columns. This is also often
found in practice since breaking down a datastructure into
scalars can be clumsy and inefficient.

This way you can use SQL to run Prolog with lists and/or
compounds. A typical solution will not be able to fully 
translate Prolog clauses or queries to SQL but also need
some code in the host language that issues the SQL 
commands. You might sacrifice some flexibility of unification
and instead implement so called allowed deductive databases
that are not anymore datalog in the presence of lists 
and/or compounds.

Best Regards